# Web page not displaying tinyMCE formated text

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, tinymce-4

Formatted text is stored in database properly with all tags and when I inspect element on my webpage for example it says `<strong>something</strong>` but it is not displayed as bold/strong.

In my head tag I have the source being called and tinyMCE initialized, like so :

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
  tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

What could it be?

Comment: Please show an example of what is stored in the database versus what is displayed on the page.

Comment: in database i have <p><strong>admir</strong></p> but on a web page normal text without strong style

Comment: Perhaps some CSS is conflicting with the `<strong>` tags? It's difficult to troubleshoot without an example.

Comment: i have no css rules that conflict with <strong>,<i>,<h1> to <h6> tags

Comment: how is textarea value being set?

Comment: @charlietfl <textarea name="text1"><?php echo $text1;?></textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector:'textarea',
    valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br"
});
```

Comment: Try refreshing the page few times to make sure you are not loading cached version.

Comment: go to www.motel-bosna.tk and open "Cjenik" category in navigation.Inspect element on text and you will see some strong tags but it is not displayed.For exapmle <div class="front_text"><div><strong>Cjenik noćenja</strong></div></div>

Comment: i refreshed few times and still nothing i even deleted everything and started to format text from beggining but again nothing

Comment: remove: font: inherit;" from style.css on line 18

Comment: you have a css reset that makes `strong` have font-weight normal. Simple to inspect in browser dev tools

Comment: just remove font: inherit; from style.css (line 18)

Comment: @Tom ok i removed font:inherit and now it works.Thak you guys